# Is there any difference between multiple databases and single database when using a single mysql server?

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a mysql server.

And I need to run wordpress and discuz on it, there are two ways to use the mysql server:

1. create two databases in mysql, one for wordpress and the other one for discuz
2. create only one database in mysql, the two shares the database.

Which one provides better mysql performance?

Thanks!

Comment: create one database and have them separate tables each.

Comment: does this provide better performance and why?

Answer (score 0):

actually as far as I can tell it's almost the same, but just a readability issue, lots of websites are hosted on a server that allows only a single db, in that case, you can use the same db with different table prefixes'for example' to enhance readability, other than that, it's almost the same, no performance issues, but on the other side, having to data bases, will allow you to track problems on the db server like overload and things like that easier since you will know already where it's coming from. I hope that's enough.

Answer (score 0):

for some software engineering point of view, maybe use two databases is better.
(Ok, if there is no too much big data in your databases, it nearly make no difference but if your data is big enough it's better to seperate and manage independently. mostly good engineering work is forcast work of performance, so that's my suggestion maybe it's not a good answer.)

Comment: What you say is true, *from a certain point of view*, but this doesn't rea address the question that is being asked.

Comment: Ok, if there is no too much big data in your databases, it nearly make no difference but if your data is big enough it's better to seperate and manage independently. mostly good engineering work is forcast work of performance, so that's my suggestion maybe it's not a good answer.